# DI Software constructors or get/set - best practice

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I am currently creating my own dependency injection software but am finding that it seems a lot like do this, do that to get this (if that makes sense).

```
class FactoryDatabase extends PDO
{
    public function __construct(
        $dsn,$user,$pass
    ) {
        parent::__construct($dsn,$user,$pass);
    }
}

class DependencyInjectionContainer
{
    protected $Con;
    public function __construct(
        $db_factory
    ) {
        $this->Con = $db_factory;
    }
}

$container = new DependencyInjectionContainer(new FactoryDatabase(....
```

I am not fully understanding where to use constructors and where to use set/get methods since there is too many possibilities of achieving this.

For better practice, I'd like to understand if its better to use constructors or methods like these:

```
protected $Callbacks;
public function set(
    $foo,$bar
) {
    if(!empty($this->Callbacks[$foo]))    {
        $this->Callbacks[$foo] = $bar;
    }
}

$container = new DependencyInjectionContainer();
$container->set('db', new FactoryDatabase(......
```

But now I get a problem where creating a get method will allow direct access to the database object rather than only through the DI container object.

I thought of a come around using both constructors and get/set methods:

```
public function __construct(
    FactoryDatabase $db
) {
    $this->Con = $db;
}

public function getFunction(
    $foo
) {
    return $this->Callbacks[$foo]($this);
}

public function getValue(
    $foo
) {
    return $this->Callbacks[$foo];
}
```

This allows me to use the Callbacks as values or anonymous functions but also access the methods inside the function, something like:

```
$container->set('db_select_members', function($obj){
    return $obj->....
});
```

Is this best practice? Or how can I improve this DI software to allow full dynamics keeping Objects unclear to other Objects.

The only issue again is now there is direct access through the anonymous function to objects which could of just been accessed like:

```
$container->Object
```

So it seems a waste of time?

Answer (score -2):

In most ceses best is to use tested and ready to use libs like symfony di (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html)

If you realy need to write your own best use is to create class with get-ers like

https://justpaste.it/vlpm

etc

and use only container as replacement for factories

Comment: There is no point creating an Object and enclosing it into another object just to return it (that isn't DI); also, this doesn't provide anything that I can use neither states a best practice and why. I already stated I was creating my own and am not looking for out-sources. I appreciate the time though.

Comment: Where are you calling `$this->container->get('db')` from? because to me it looks like a service locator rather than doing dependency injection

Comment: Hey, completely off-topic but are you working on any projects or fancy working on one? @PeeHaa

Comment: BTW if you are interested in DI you may want to have a look into https://github.com/rdlowrey/auryn for inspiration.

Comment: Well, its not the interest in DI, I just prefer well written code when writing long-period projects. I have my own business and a few contracts to agencies, we supply the online solutions and they supply their business aspects through them however, since they're custom built CMS's with dashboards ect, after a while they come hard to maintain so I need a way of producing additions @PeeHaa

Comment: @KyleThomas  this is how DI in symfony  works (in simple implementation).

Comment: Far from it, Symfony uses locators yes but this is not DI at all @fazi DI is similar to a hierarchy but for code (objects), just like basic DS protocols you need locators which you're right but I am looking for a solution to DI not locators

Comment: @KyleThomas Ok. I check my old code and indeed I have write something similar to yours. https://justpaste.it/vlpm

Comment: Yes, but your answer only provides an external source and information about locators which is far from the Question. @fazi